# I use js to dynamically generate some forms but the data cannot be passed to the backend

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

As described in the problem

I create two buttons. The one is used to add forms,the other one is used to submit data.However, after inputting data when i clicked on the button of submit,it didn't work

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8"
    pageEncoding="utf-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>GA'S WEB APPLY</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>var i=1</script>
    <p>test is ing!</p>
    <hr>
    <div>
    <form action="/webTest/TestWeb" method="post">
    <input type=button onclick="document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd','<input type=text name='+i+' value='+i+++'> ')" value=add />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem in your code is with `''` quotes as well as ,whenever you append new `input` it appear out of `<form></form>` tag , so whenever you submit your form that value doesn't passed to your `backened` page and will always return `null`. Instead do like below :

```js
var i = 1
$(document).ready(function() {
 //location to add new inputs
  var to_Add_at = $(".inputs");
  var add_button = $("input[name='add']");
  //on click of button
  $(add_button).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(to_Add_at).append('<input type=text name='+i+' value='+i++ +'>'); //add input box

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/webTest/TestWeb" method="post">
  <input type="button"  value="add" name="add" />
  <div class="inputs"></div>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Where should I put the first part of the code? It seems that embedding directly in the javascript tag or jsp file has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

As I can not see the backend data or anything else besides the code. I would say 
1. File location wrong? 
2. Page language should be javascript
3. Add quatations "" around value = add